# Is there any way to find the Apple ID of the activation lock?

Tags: apple-id, iphone, activation-lock

I understand it is impossible to find the password, but is it possible to find the apple ID so I can email the guy this phone was obviously stolen off? I've lost several hundred pounds on this stupid purchase, but at the very least I can give this poor man his phone back.

Dubhlainn

Comment: short answer… no. Hand it to the police.

Comment: I did, they checked the IMEI number, said it was american, and gave it back with the claim that there was nothing they could do.
013850004472828 <-- There it is if anyone can help!

Comment: then you're back to the short answer, I'm afraid. it's a brick to all but the iCloud account holder. Let it connect to the net, see if they post a message to it. Last one I lost I dropped a msg to call another number & someone did - i got it back. Some people are honest & some people hope for honesty… should the twain meet, there is potential.